# MongoDB: Is there any advantage to a compound index that includes '_id'?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Queries look like this:

```
db.myCollection.find({_id: {$in: [...]}, isActive: true})
```

`_id` is a regular `ObjectId` and `isActive` is a bool assigned to each document.

Is there any performance advantage from using an index like `{_id: 1, isActive: 1}`? On one hand, `_id` is a unique field and already indexed, so any additional indexing would be superfluous. On the other hand, there might be a gain, however slight, from Mongo being able to toss out non-matching documents (i.e. `isActive = false`) by examining only the index.

Comment: one way to find out is to create the compound index  and use `.explain()` and see what happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a good idea to use a compound index. However, since the isActive field can have only two values, a better index would be

```
{isActive: 1, _id: 1}
```

This would make sure that only those objects who are active are processed in the next step.